# How do I get user input as parameter in a 404 page?

Tags: php, apache, iis

Say I have a website `http://site.com`. When a user surfs a non-existing page `http://site.com/whatever.html`, a default 404 page `http://site.com/default.php` is displayed.

How can I get what the user tried to surf? (get `whateve.html` in this case).

Is this a common feature?

Comment: Have you tried `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`?

Comment: Are you _redirecting_ your user to the so called 404 page using 301/302 header? It is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Its in the Apache/Nginx error logs.

You can grep the file for 404

Answer (score 0):

Using **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**, you should get the filename the user requested.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might vary depending upon the server that you are using. For common servers like Apache & Nginx - if you type in `http://site.com/whatever.html` & if whatever.html doesn't exist then the **content** of 404 page (set in server configurations) will be displayed , but the URL location will be the same `whatever.html`.

If you want to pass parameters to your 404 page, you can try something like Regex to get your catched/matched value & pass it to 404 page, but I can't give you an exact answer since it depends upon which server you are using. Do let us know if this works or this is what you were looking for, will try to help more.